# Firebase Appinvites return with resultCode 3

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I want to try out app-invites from firebase - unfortunately onActivityResult reports back with onActivityResult 3.
Using only the code from this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android

I get:

```
requestCode=101, resultCode=3
```

Before I could select a contact and saw the title and text I passed - unfortunately no hint in the log.

SHA-1 is entered and working for the app ( already successfully using firebase analytics in there )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the release SHA-1 added in the firebase console - but not the debug SHA-1 key - adding this one solved the issue